# how to copy columns from one spreadsheet and paste into another in open office

Tags: javascript, java, python, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I have some repetitive and tedious work to do. I am using open office.
These are the common steps that i have to do daily:-
1)Copy one column from one .csv file and paste into open office spreadsheet column.
2)Copy range of column say 7 and paste into open office spreadsheet column.
3)Remove extra lines from bottom.

I want these tasks to be done on a single click.
please tell me how to use calc for this.

Comment: Why is this tagged Python?

Comment: Because python as macro is used in open office.

Comment: [Afaik, it is not.](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide)

Comment: It is. please visit this link https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language

Comment: Interesting. But I've never seen anybody using it here on SO or asking a similar question. Good luck finding somebody, who is familiar with that implementation.